# Unexpected gcc warning for Attribute specifier sequence

Tags: c++, gcc

### Expected behavior

In a C++ code I have the following function:

```cpp
static void log(const char* format, ...)
{
    ...
}
```

Compilation by gcc (with `-std=c++11`) gives me the following warning:
`function ‘static void Logger::log(const char*, ...)’ might be a candidate for ‘gnu_printf’ format attribute`.
The warning does not show any more if I modify the code like this:

```cpp
static void log(const char* format, ...) __attribute__ ((format (printf, 1, 2)))
{
    ...
}
```

So far so good.

### The problem

In order to be portable I'd like to use an [Attribute specifier sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes) instead of `__attribute__`. So I try to modify the code again:

```cpp
[[gnu::format(printf, 1, 2)]]
static void log(const char* format, ...)
{
    ...
}
```

But in this case the warning appears again. Is the warning just a false positive or am I doing something incorrectly?

Version of gcc used:
`12.2.1 20220830 [revision e927d1cf141f221c5a32574bde0913307e140984]`

Comment: afaik warnings aren't portable anyways

Comment: I suggest you try to avoid vararg functions in C++. They aren't type-safe, and you can't use C++ objects unless you make up your own formatting code (which will make GCC complain since they aren't "standard" `printf` formats). Use *template parameter packs* instead.I suggest you look into [the fmtlib library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) (and which was the base for [the C++ formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) added in C++20).